# Should I upgrade to VS2015 or VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio, bluetooth, uwp

I have some legacy code built with VS2012. The code is native Win32 C++, and it targets Windows 7 and above.

Now, I am required to add Windows-10 native Bluetooth support. After some research, I decided to use [UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/). For this I must upgrade my IDE and toolset.

My question is: is there any reason to upgrade to VS2015, and not go directly to VS2017?

Comment: Versions of VS are installed side by side: you can thus easily switch to try things out.

Comment: you can install multiple versions of visual studio, using vs 2015 you can build  windows and windows phone 8.1 apps but not with vs2017 but win form app can be made both and if you want to develop uwp by using vs 2015 you can max use windows 10.0.14393 sdk for above you must use vs 2017 for implementing fluent design system. in my opinion install both vs2015 or vs 2017 , i am also using both. because if you target above uwp 10.0.14393  some phones is not upgraded to above this version , so i am using 10.0.14393